# Generate CSS from scssc file in .sass-cache

Tags: css, caching, sass, frontend

I'm wondering what exactly the .scssc file in the .sass-cache folder does and whether it can be used to generate CSS or SCSS if the original scss file has been wiped.

When I open the file in .sass-cache I get thousands of hexidecimals (I think). Is this in any way able to be parsed into CSS or SCSS. And if not, what does this cache file do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is default behaviour as caches are compiled from pieces of your code (partials etc). It speeds up compilation process of large number of files.

I don't think you can reproduce your original css / scss from cache.